# Pushing notification in background

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want to know how to push notification with out letting user know that a push notification is received.Just my application should be aware of the notification and do the task required depended upon notification.

Comment: it can be achieved from overridden method onMessage of GCMBaseIntentService that you have used to implement your GCM service. just dont notify the user from this method.

Comment: Please can you post some code how to push this?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService
{
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
    if (intent.getExtras().containsKey("payload"))
    {
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("payload");
        CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        //generateNotification(context, message);
    }

   }
}
```

here in this method dont notify user when the message comes.

**EDIT:**

this answer is applicable only if you have used GCM directly in your app implemented by yourself. 
If you are using parse.com for this then you cant achieve what you have asked in question. because parse API internally notifies this user.

Comment: Hey but I am using parse.GCMBaseIntentService class is not showing